# Yii2 how to change text colour of navbar

Tags: colors, yii2, navbar

I want to ask you how to change a colour of text in navbar (where is the Home, About,...) in Yii2 framework basic template? I've tried so many things but nothing worked. Thank you for reply!

Comment: I have update my answer with your code .. and yes .. the first answer was for <li> tag  now i have add the code for the link too..

Comment: A suggestion .. don't use answer for post your code .. edit  instead the original question and do a comment for alert your audience ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of the text of the `<a>` element (the link ) of navbar the color is defined inside the bootstrap.min.css.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
background-color: #1a242f;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

Then if you want to change the css then you must change the bootstrap.css and the minimize ..

A simple way is change directly the style in the layout  ..

changing directly the style of the item using options for the li tag and linkOption for the related link

```
<?php
  NavBar::begin([
      'brandLabel' => 'Name',
      'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
      'options' => [
          'class' => 'my-navbar navbar-fixed-top',
      ],
  ]);
  echo Nav::widget([
      'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
      'items' => [
          ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index'], 'options' => ['style' => 'background-color: #F00;']],
          ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']], 'linkOptions' => ['style' => 'color: #000;']],
          Yii::$app->user->isGuest ?
              ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']] :
              [
                  'label' => 'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                  'url' => ['/site/logout'],
                  'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']
              ],
      ],
  ]);
  NavBar::end();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not

```
'options' => ['style' => 'color: #000;']]
```

but

```
'linkOptions' => ['style' => 'color: #000;']]
```

linkOptions works! Color changed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `'linkOptions' => ['style' => 'color: #000;']]`

I did `'linkOptions' => ['class' => 'myCssClass']]`

This worked for me